# Configure WorkManager in JBoss 7

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm pretty new with JSF (I'm a mobile developer) and I need to run a bulk of processes in a thread.
I've read I need to use WorkManager, but I can't find how is that, and how to configure it in JBoss 7.

Does anyody know an easy-to-follow tutorial about that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

An `@Aysnchronous` EJB is probably the easiest solution.

**Edit 1:**

This will look more or less like this:

```
@Singleton
public BulkProcessor {

    @Asynchronous
    public void doWork(){
        // code there
    }
}
```

When you invoke the method it will immediately return but JBoss will then run `#doWork` in it's own thread. Just remember you'll have to `@Inject` the object and not instantiate it yourself.

**Edit 2:**

This is a quick and easy example
http://satishgopal.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/ejb-3-1-asynchronous-methods/

Comment: How's that? I'm pretty new at this.